# Creating Build Configuration via REST in Teamcity

Tags: rest, teamcity-7.0

Is it possible to create a new build configuration for an existing project via REST api(POST method) in Teamcity?
If so, how to create? (some guidelines )

Thanks

Comment: Hey, have you managed to do this? If yes, could you please show and explain an example?

Comment: Hi.. whatEver given as answer by Arpit has all the required Rest api.. u can refer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for sure possible on 8.x, haven't the need to care about early versions.

Here's a really simple python snippet that will copy an existing build config into a given project using this as a guide [http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings.](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings)

```
import requests

xml =  """<newBuildTypeDescription name='NewBuildConfigName'
          sourceBuildTypeLocator='ExistingBuildConfigNameThatYouWantToCopy'
          copyAllAssociatedSettings='true' shareVCSRoots='false'/>
       """
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} # set what your server accepts

print requests.post('http://YOURTEAMCITYWEBADDRESS:YOURTEAMCITYPORT/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/id:PROJECTIDWHERENEWBUILDCONFIGSHOULDBECREATED/buildTypes', data=xml, headers=headers, auth=('TeamCityUserName','TeamCityPassword')).text
```

Answer (score 3):

Its now possible in [8.x REST](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings). You can do something like:

```
POST plain text (name) to http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/<projectLocator>/buildTypes
```

Above is copied from [8.x REST](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings). Check [8.x REST](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not implemented in the REST API. Have a look at [this](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/rest-api/trunk-protocol-7.0/src/jetbrains/buildServer/server/rest/request/BuildTypeRequest.java)

There is no way to create a build configuration. You can add build steps to it and configure them, but it doesn't seem to be implemented in the API at all. I was actually fighting with this myself last night. If you find a way to do it, please let me know.

Also, you could have a look at these [notes](https://gist.github.com/carlspring/6762356) I've put together concerning the Teamcity REST API. (Not that they're answering this question, but some of them could be quite useful).

Answer (score -5):

Well, you can refer to [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) for starters:

Comment: If you actually have a look at it, you'll see there is no way mentioning how to create a build configuration via the REST API.